# Hibernate "where"-annoation in inherit class

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, where-clause

I have an entity (store) which is inherited from it's superclass (location).
Stores and locations have it's own tables (InheritanceType "joined").

The location has an attribute (active).

In another entity, I have a list of stores (OneToMany-relationship). These list should only contain the active stores. 
I annotated it with

```
@Where(clause="active = 'Y'")
```

But It does not work:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'stores0_.active' in 'where clause'
```

because the table "stores" does not have the "active"-property, it's parent has (which is an own table). Is there a parent selector for the where-annotation or is there  better solution?

Location:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "locations")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Location {
    [..]

    @Column(name = "active")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private Boolean isActive;
```

Store:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "store")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName= "id")  
public class Store extends Location {

    [..]
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "shop_id")
    private Shop shop;
```

Shop:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shop")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
public class Shop extends Location {
    [...]



    @Where(clause="active = 'Y'")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="shop")
    private List<Store> stores;
```

Comment: Can you post your entity code fragment?